# How to fire device PIN dialog?

Tags: ios, swift, security, authorization

I working on an app that is designed to be protected from unauthorized access (like, for instance, bank apps do). There are two protection options: by using biometrics (default one) and by user password. I wonder, what the best practices are to handle the situation when a user forget thier password.
I'm thinking to prompt user to enter device PIN in order to remind them the password, but I can't figure out how to do that.

Comment: If your app lets them use biometrics then you are already using the local authentication framework.  This is all you need to get the user to enter their passcode.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it really depends on exactly how sensible the information is and how you're currently storing/validating the password. But assuming your threat model is okay with a user being able to get access back just with the current device password, you could use the keychain API (not the friendliest of APIs) and store some kind of flag. When adding such item you would use `SecAccessControlCreateFlag.devicePasscode` which will always prompt the user for their iPhone passcode before accessing such entry. So say the user needs to reset it, if you're able to access the keychain entry, you know they entered the right device passcode and thus you should allow them to reset their app password. The main caveat would be that the user disabling their passcode or not having one would invalidate your flag so they would be locked out forever if they ever forget their app password. Of course there's a lot of additional nuance to the Keychain like whether the items get synced to other devices or not, when it's available, etc. but hopefully this is somewhat useful.